# Java library to separate a multi-page TIFF file into several PNG or JPG files

Tags: library, java, image-conversion, tiff

I want to find to separate [multi tiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Multiple_subfiles) files to png or jpg in Java.

I tried JAI, but it has a lot of bug something, especially with jpeg-2000.

so I want to find another third-party library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEADTOOLS Imaging Pro SDK technology in your application.
https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats

You can leverage the RasterCodecs class, to loop through each page of a multi-page TIFF file and export each page individually to any LEADTOOLS supported file format (PNG, JPEG, BMP, etc.).

**DISCLOSURE: I am an employee of the company offering this toolkit.**

Here is some sample code:

```
String multipageFile = "FILE PATH TO MULTIPAGE FILE";
RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs();
int totalPages = codecs.getTotalPages(multipageFile);
for (int page = 1; page <= totalPages; page++)
{
    String outputFile = "<EXPORT_DIR>\\SplitTiff(page" + page + ").png";
    RasterImage image = codecs.load(multipageFile, page);
    codecs.save(image, outputFile, RasterImageFormat.PNG, image.getBitsPerPixel()); // Change to RasterImageFormat.JPEG for .jpg
    image.dispose();
}
```